# Поиск элемента массива из целых чисел который повторяется

Tags: c, массивы

> Нужно найти элемент, который повторяется в массиве челых чисел 
>   которые вводятся с клавиатуры

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define SIZE 7
    int main (void)
    {
        int array[SIZE];
        int bf_mn = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
          while((scanf("%d", &array[i])) == 1)
          {
            bf_mn = array[i-1];   // Проблемная
           if(array[i] == bf_mn)  // часть
          {
            printf("try again: ");
            continue;
          }
          printf("%d ", array[i]);
          }
        }
        puts("");

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
bool is_exist(int * data, int idx) {
  for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
    if (data[i] == data[idx])
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

..................

int array[SIZE];
int bf_mn = 0;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  while ((scanf("%d", & array[i])) == 1) {
    if (is_exists(array, i))
    {
      printf("try again: ");
      i--;
      continue;
    }
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает)

Answer (score 0):

*Точность - вежливость программистов.*

Что значит "повторяется"? Вы не хотите допускать двух одинаковых значений подряд?

И что такое "Проблемная часть"? В чем заключается "проблема" мы должны сами догадаться?

```
if (i > 0) 
{  
  if (array[i] == array[i-1])
  {
    i--;
    printf("try again: ");
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: da, именно это, нужно найти элемент который повторяется и заменить ево новым(ету проблему решает часть где есть continue, моя проблема в том что я не могу сформулировать условие)

Comment: @AlexBelz Теперь - можете ).